# Localizing buttons of a FacesContext.addMessage in adf

Tags: oracle-adf

Hi i want to localize the buttons eg: OK, Cancel in ADF,

I am using the following code

FacesContext fctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
fctx.addMessage(VALIDATIONERROR,new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,                             errorMessage, errorMessage));
fctx.renderResponse();

I get the pop and the error message is localized, My question is how to localize the buttons which are on the pop up, ex: OK,CANCEL

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are talking about a af:dialog component. In that case i can think about two ways of doing so:

1. The af:dialog component has two properties: cancelTextAndAccessKey and affermativeTextAndAccessKey. They can take an EL which can take the key of a specific record into a .properties file (which is loaded as a resource bundle into the project. An example: cancelTextAndAccessKey="#{lang['popUp.dialog.button.cancel']}" (where lang is the name of the declared bundle in my case)
2. You can override the default component label, by creating a ListResourceBundle (which should be also loaded as a resource bundle into faces-config.xml, Application tab).

   The code should be something like:

   public class CTSResourceBundle extends ListResourceBundle {

   ```
     public CTSResourceBundle() {
         super();
     }


   @Override
   protected Object[][] getContents() {
           return new Object[][] {
                  { "af_dialog.LABEL_YES", "Po" },
                  { "af_dialog.LABEL_NO", "Jo" },
                  { "af_dialog.LABEL_OK", "Ok" },
                  { "af_dialog.LABEL_CANCEL", "Anullo" }
       };
     }
   }
   ```